# need help on running different enviroments on GIT or with a CI/CD pipeline

Tags: python, git, continuous-integration, devops, cicd

I am have been a python developer for a small startup for many years.  Recently the company started growing and now that I am not the only developer in the team we are standarizing on certain stuff.  One of the issues we are running into is how to use different enviroments with GIT and/or with a CI/CD pipeline.  We develop locally on our laptops or on our local enviroment we built.  Then we push to a Dev enviroment and then to Prod.  When we do this a script changes some of the files and added or removes stuff such as ENV variables, DB's, and/or security stuff.  This works fine, until we ran into a bug in Prod.  We create a hotfix branch fix it and now merge it in prod and then merge those changes back into the other branches.  Now we have all of our Prod ENV, config and DB's in our local enviroment.  Not only is it taking us time to figure out what happened, but we accidently deleted a table in Prod thinking we were on our local enviroment.  Since then, we have tried Git hooks which is supposed to run a script upon checkout of a branch, but cant seem to get it quite right and the other thing is that I would need to add the script to the .git directory in the repo which no one does.  The .git directory is ignored in most cases.  I have looked at other options, but cant seem to find a good explanation or "best practice" for this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: A lot of things here, like you should have fully automated migrations management and generally deployment to production should be fully automated. Feel free to find me at DevOps Community Discord - devopscommunity.org - as it's probably too much for SO to discuss.

Comment: Man, question is totally not readable. Please, split on blocks, omit the redundant text if it does not affect anything.